# How does assembler process "org 100h" directive?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I know, what this directive is do. As I know program-loader doesn't see this directive, so, how assembler process it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sets the current address during assembly to be 100h. That's all it is. A simple assignment.

Elaboration:

The directive does not control where in the result image the following instructions will be placed, but rather where the instructions would be placed after being loaded into memory.

Comment: As I understand, it is only assign 100h-adress for first command in program?

Comment: If it is at the start of the program, the first instruction/data and/or label following it will be regarded as residing at address 100h. Anything follow it in turn will reside directly after it and so on.

Answer (score 1):

"org <100h>" instructs the **compiler** with the to-be runtime information to evaluate addresses, as binary image will be loaded with offset (and first 100h bytes possibly to be used for PSP etc. in your context)

This comes in hand to access any data in the same segment (usually when DS=CS, especially true for com files when "you know nothing except your CS"), or when doing a JMP to absolute offset in rare cases.

In other words, it makes all further labels in a segment to account from the specific offset: just that.

Comment: `jcc` and near `jmp` instructions are a poor example; they're always relative (and position-independent).  A better example would be `mov ax, [my_word]`, where the addressing mode will use a disp16 with an absolute address (relative to the DS segment base).

Comment: But the first paragraph is correct.  Depending on your assembler (NASM vs. MASM), that is *all* `org 100h` does.  https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.1  (NASM doesn't let you use ORG to go back and overwrite some previously-assembled output.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes -- redacted to clarify the statement and removed the wrong example. "Constant vigilance" as it is ))

Answer (score -2):

Mostly programs when loaded in Windows it used to start from 100
So when we wrote org 100h it tells in run time to compiler to store data starting from 100 .i.e if u use 60h or 70h 
Compiler will produce error of data may be present at 60 or your given location

Comment: No, only DOS `.com` programs are loaded there (at that offset relative to the DS segment base).  Windows programs are loaded at much higher addresses.  And no, `org 100h` doesn't tell the assembler *where* to store the data, it tells the assembler what address it will be loaded at, so it can emit correct absolute addresses.