# How do I efficiently implement the ORIGIN assembler directive in my hypothetical instruction set?

Tags: c++, assembly

I am building an assembler as a college assignment to implement a Hypothetical instruction set. In the set, there is a directive called `ORIGIN [address]`. This directive simply changes the Location Counter to the specified [address] exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321808/how-does-assembler-process-org-100h-directive). The directive can take the address either as an immediate operand, or as a displacement with respect to a `Label`. I am unable to efficiently code this into [my assembler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240578/a-lousy-assembler?noredirect=1#comment471981_240578). Please help.

I imagined it to be something on the following lines,

```
1. It searches for the + sign
std::find(statement.back().begin(), statement.back().end(), '+')); //put it in if condition and compare 
                                                                     it with statement.back().end()
2. If the sign is present, then it gets 2 tokens:
auto line = const_cast<char*>(statement.back());
auto tok1 = strtok(line, "+");
auto tok2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");
long val1 = 0;
long val2 = 0;
for (const auto& row : SYMTAB) {
    if(row.name == tok1) {
        val1 = row.LC_val;
    }
    if(row.name == tok2) {
        val2 = row.LC_val;
    }
}
LOCCTR = va1 + val2;
3. If the sign is not present, then it searches the SYMTAB for the Label and gets the LC
auto tok = strtok(line,"\n");
for(const auto& row : SYMTAB) {
    if(row.name == tok) {
        LOCCTR = row.LC_val;
    }
}
```

What I am puzzled about is how will I differentiate between immediate operand and Label with number in it.

The code is also supposed to be able to recognize a chain of `+` like `Label1+Label2+Label3+4`, which I guess is not possible with the thought I followed.

Comment: _"In the set, there is an instruction called `ORIGIN <address>`"_ But elsewhere you say it's a **directive** (which makes more sense); so it's **not** an instruction, and therefor not part of the instruction set.

Comment: Does your symbol table not hold any information about the type of each symbol? I'm just wondering why it would be a problem to tell the difference between a label and a numeric literal?

Comment: You're going to want a wrapper function for symbol table lookups.  You'll want to use a data structure that supports O(1) lookups, like `std::unordered_map<string,unsigned long>`.  It's kind of insane to be using `<algorithm>` helpers like `std::find` but then manually inlining a linear search over a container.  Also, you probably want to try parsing it as a number first.  `strtoul` returns enough info to let you tell if conversion failed (non-digits therefore symbol name) or if it succeeded even if the number was an explicit `0`.

Comment: Re: "Does your symbol table not hold any information about the symbol?" :- Labels are declared with `:` at end, and are stored so. Normal variables don't have `:` at the end. 
I was talking about differentiating between `ORIGIN Label1+3` and `ORIGIN Label1+Label3`. Also, my code in the question takes only 1 plus symbol, whereas it is expected to recognize even a chain of `+`.. like `Label1+Label2+Label3+4`..... you get the idea

Comment: Numbers are distinguished from labels in that labels cannot begin with digits and numbers always do.

Comment: this is your assembler at the end of the day you define the assembly language you are therefore free to use whatever syntax you want if you want to say !origiin!address$ to make it easier to parse then do so.  the other note here is that putting addresses in asm is not unheard of it was the norm but now that the assembler is part of a toolchain that includes a linker you could just have the tool rely on a linker although that is more work or you can defaut the starting address and rely on that.  otherwise this is pretty easy to parse and use compared to instructions

Comment: `strtok` is only appropriate for the simplest very regular syntax-es, like maybe a csv file.  for anything else, it is horrible because you will need more and more delimiters but it also wipes them out.  you're better off simply stepping through the characters one byte at a time and handling them as you see them.  Also consider whether you allow spaces in between, e.g. `ORIGIN label  +   3`.  Don't go down the rathole of trying to make `strtok` work.

Comment: Good assembler should cope with directives like `ORIGIN Label1 - Label2+Label3`,  `ORIGIN $ - (2*4)`, `ORIGIN 4+Label1` etc. You need to write an expression evaluator instead of manual parsing of statement field whenever an expression is expected. See also https://euroassembler.eu/easource/exp.htm#ExpEval

Comment: @vitsoft, that takes things to a whole new level